# measuring significant differences between features of two subsets of the same data

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, survey

I have a dataset with 700ish samples of survey results. Things like height, weight, etc and someone wants to know if there is a statistical difference between the people who said yes to question A (~300) and those who said no (~400).

My initial thought was a 2 sample t-test between the two subgroups, but should I be using a paired t-test instead? (or should I be using something else entirely?)

Also, they want me to tell if there is a statistical difference across 17 variables, and I said I would need to account for false significance with the bonferroni correction to the .05 p-value threshold. Was that the correct correction?

Comment: Maybe too many issues here for one Q // What foundation for 'pairing' between subjects who Yes to A and No to A? // As for use of a two-sample t test, are data close to normal? If these are Likert scores, then it might even be somewhat controversial to treat ordinal categorical scores as numeric. Two-sample Wilcoxon test might be appropriate. // Bonferroni correction for 17 tests might be over-conservative (require too small a P-value for rejection). A more detailed discussion of how the 17 tests arise might enable someone here to suggest a more feasible method of avoiding 'false discovery'.

Comment: They're results from a medical survey about whether or not they told their health provider about certain types of pain. I didn't think about normality, I will use a non-parametric test! Most of the statistics are body/health metrics. The 17 tests is also a bit missleading, as its 12 on the question A, then another 4 on a subset of the people who said yes to A.